# Closed formula for system's entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Suppose there exists a circle of radius $r$ and $n$ identical bouncing balls within this circle. Suppose this system has entropy $S$. Now reduce the radius to $r/2$ with the same number of bouncing balls. Then, let $S'$ be the system's new entropy. Is there any closed formula for $S' - S$?

Perhaps the question needs some extra assumptions. If it is the case, let me know and I will edit the post.

Comment: Assuming you're working in the thermodynamic limit, then it would depend on how the process takes place. Is it adiabatic? Isothermal? Etc.

On a more fundamental (or microscopic, if you want) level though, entropy is a measure of occupation of microstates. You'd need a way to count those

Comment: Since i do not know any of this concepts, it may be easier to just assume each case inductively.

Comment: There are many cases you can consider. Relating changes in entropy with macroscopic quantities and calculating entropy changes for different macroscopic processes, especially in the simpler case of an ideal gas, is pretty standard in thermodynamics books, I believe. I would start there